# Когда дебажу в браузере с помощью ionic serve все ts файлы становатся js файлами и труднее дебажить

Tags: npm, ionic, ionicframework, ionic2, ionic3

Когда дебажу в браузере с помощью ionic serve все ts файлы становатся js файлами и труднее дебажить. Как сделать чтоб ts файлы не конвертились в js файлы.

Comment: как по вашему браузер будет понимать `.ts` файлы без компилирования в `.js`?

Comment: раньше когда я ionic serve делал он сохранял ts файли и я по ним дебажил @overthesanity

Comment: он не сохраняет ts файлы, браузер парсит source-maps, не зная конфигурацию вашего проекта - сложно что-то сказать, `ionic-webpack` из коробки генерирует source-maps, только если вы вручную не отключили. Как вариант попробуйте в `package.json` создать свойство `"config":{
     "ionic_source_map": "source_map"
}`